# Not getting the option to add Systemconfiguration framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am in Xcode 4.5.I have an application in which i need to add sysconfiguration framework.But when i try to add sysconfiguration framework it was not coming there,in the options .it was not available.But when i tried in xcode 4.3 it was there.I think i accidently deleted that from xcode 4.5.What i need to do now to get it back?

Comment: might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433804/how-to-add-deleted-frameworks-again

Comment: @minjiera it is therein that folder.I have deleted it from 4.5.i am using 3 xcodes in my mac.