# UIKit.h file not found on real iOS decvice

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I am trying to test a sample iOS application which runs with no problems on the simulator, while building fails on a real iOS device, with the following error:
"UIKit/UIKit.h not found". The file that generates the error is "TestRealDevice-Prefix.pch"

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'TestRealDevice' target in the 'TestRealDevice' project
//
#import <Availability.h>
#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

The UIKit.framework, Foundation.framework and CoreGraphics.framework have red color in the "Build Phases" tab!

I tried to run a sample project without modifying any thing in it, but i have the same error

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ahmed just wanted to ask if one of the solutions below answered your problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove UIKit, Foundation and CoreGraphics frameworks from the Build Phases tab and add them again.

Comment: I tried, but after removing them and try adding them again they don't appear in the available frameworks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't building the app for OSX instead of iOS. This can happen or a variety of reasons including updating XCode. XCode seems to default to OSX if it gets confused.

Comment: I checked it is built for iOS

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled x-code and it works fine after that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did that caused this error. And the solution is at: [How to add deleted frameworks again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433804/how-to-add-deleted-frameworks-again)

If you haven't emptied the trash yet, close Xcode and open the Trash in Finder. Find the framework folder you accidentally deleted. In Finder, open another window for Macintosh HD\System\Library\Frameworks, and drag-copy the framework from the Trash to the Frameworks folder. Reopen Xcode and you should be able to add the framework again in the target settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be in Build Settings -> Valid Architecture there are arm64. So just remove the architecture arm64 and problem solved.