# How to recover deleted libxml2.dylib

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4.6

I have deleted accidently `libxml2.dylib` and `libxml2.2.dylib` from project and where we placed framework. Now I retry to add this from framework. I can't see this framework any more. I added this from my other project but it gives error `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. I am stuck over here. kindly help to recover this issue this will be great for me. Thanks in advance. cheers.

Comment: check out this link....... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433804/how-to-add-deleted-frameworks-again

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see them in your Frameworks that means you have sent them to trash. If you have emptied your trash Consequently they are permanently deleted from your sdk too. You need to get them  back by re installing sdk or get exactly two .frameworks files somewhere online. Else check your trash if you are lucky enough and restore them :)